# Python regex , two negative lookahead statements

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string of syntactically parsed text:

```
 s = 'ROOT (S (VP (VP (VB the) (SBAR (S (NP (DT same) (NN lecturer)) (VP (VBZ says)'
```

I'd like to match 'the same' to s.  It's key that 'the' and 'same' only match when separated by syntactic markup (i.e, (, NP, S, etc.). So, 'the same' should NOT find a match in s2:

```
 s2= 'ROOT (S (VP (VP (VB the) (SBAR (S (NP (DT lecturer) (NN same)) (VP (VBZ says)'
```

I've tried a double negative lookahead assertion to no avail:

```
 >>>rx = r'the(?![a-z]*)same(?![a-z]*)'
 >>>re.findall(rx,s)
 []
```

The idea is to match'the' when not followed by lowercase characters and then match 'same' when not followed by lowercase characters.

Does anyone have a better approach?

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at parsing nested structures. It might be sufficient for your specific example since you don't seem to care about the nesting.

Comment: Right, the nested structure is not the problem. The same problem arises when trying to match 'the same' to the string'theABCD123sameEFG456'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to match if all of the characters between `the` and `same` are not lowercase letters, here is how you can write that in regex:

```
the[^a-z]*same
```

Note that you might want to add word boundaries as well, so you don't match something like `foothe ... samebar`, that would look like this:

```
\bthe\b[^a-z]*\bsame\b
```

Comment: That did it. I'd actually tried something like that initially, but I must have mistyped something somewhere.  In any case, thanks!